# Animation with song

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to animate a few images with a song..So I fixed the timings for animation.I am using AVFoundation.Framework.But animation is not happening at perfect time..Its taking time for loading.I tried with AudioToolbox framework also.it is working for short duration song,but not working for long duration song.How to fix this problem.Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load all images before you start playing the audio and then hide/show/animate based upon position of playbackhead in audio player.

Comment: Which framework I can use if I want to animate different image with the perfect timings of song?

Comment: You might want to look into using cocos2d it has some neat animation abilities and texture sheet abilities etc. which would help you keep memory usage down.